# How to Read from a Section of a File?

Tags: c#, binaryreader

I'm trying to read from a section of this file that had a payload stored to it when being dumped from the **Xbox**.

What I'm trying to do is read from where the payload is and if it equals to all 
`0's` then change a label to saying `No`.

I knew I am probably supposed to use `BinaryReader`, but I don't have much experience with it.
The payload starts at `0x32500` and ends at `0x3256F`.

I need this in **C#**.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can fast forward the stream when reading via the `Seek` method. Then use the `BinaryReader`'s `ReadBytes` method to read the bytes from that offset.

```
using (var br = new BinaryReader(stream)) {
    br.BaseStream.Seek(0x32500, SeekOrigin.Begin);
    var bytes = br.ReadBytes(0x3256F - 0x32500);

    if (bytes.All(x => x == 0)) {
        label.Text = "No";
    }
}
```